# useEffect with dependencies from a hook: Deconstructed or not?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, typescript-eslint

This question keeps being asked again and again but even when I ask some experts they get tangled in their fancy explanations and I never get a straight answer.

**What is the proper way of writing the list of dependencies** for useEffect when it relies on a **hook**? **deconstructed, or not?**

Deconstructed :

```
const myHookContext = useFooHook();
const { variable1, variable2 } = myHookContext;
useEffect(() => {
    if (variable1 === ...) //do whatever
  }, 
  [ variable1, variable2 ]
};
```

Not deconstructed:

```
const myHookContext = useFooHook();
useEffect(() => {
       if (myHookContext.variable1 === ...) //do whatever
   },
   [ myHookContext ]
};
```

when I use the **deconstructed** version, **ESLint complains about it.** It says that my dependencies are not right because they should include myHookContext. And I don't think that ESlint is wrong about those things.

Comment: Just tested it - eslint complains but only when using "not deconstructured" version. So it works correctly. What rule of eslint does complain in your case?

Comment: Your comment is baffling me. Let me look again.